# Как при щелчке по картинке менять одну на другую?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает! Есть картинки. Нужно, чтобы при щелчке одной из них по ней мышью они сменились на другую и так далее.

Comment: это не имеет отношение к html. Это JavaScript. 

Comment: Это минимум СSS. На чистом HTML Вы этого не как не осуществите к сожалению. 

Comment: а как на javascript это будет?Не знаете?

Comment: по клику на объект вызывается функция, которая и изменяет, что-то в документе

Comment: @антон Это отдельный вопрос...Но боюсь вам на него не кто не ответит (ибо такой закон только помощь а не написание за вас кода =]). Легче документацию нарыть.

Comment: @антон тебе типо для школы

Comment: Ну чё вы кода то всего ничего я помогу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function change(evt){
if(window.event){
img=window.event.srcElement;
}
else{
img=evt.target;
}
img.src="новое значение атрибута src";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="стандарное значение аттрибута src" onclick="change()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: извините а как делать URL подскажите

Comment: Вместо:
     
     if(window.event){
        img=window.event.srcElement;
     }
     else{
        img=evt.target;
        // да и кста - где var? глобалки в моде нынче?
     }

Лучше:

     var img = evt ? evt.target : window.event.srcElement

@антон - а URL делать точно так-же как и для тега img, что пишешьв **src** тэга то и пиши в **img.src**

Comment: И чем-же красивее? LOL

Comment: Автор никогда неделайте так var img тк если AlexWindHope незнает то переменный обьявленные внутри функции с var локальные! А глобальные без var а вне функции наоборот! Яначало почитайте книги про JS потом неправильно не будете исправлять!